# Typechat not responding with the right json format

Tags: typescript, openai-api, azure-openai

I'm using [TypeChat](https://microsoft.github.io/TypeChat/blog/introducing-typechat/) to get AzureOpenAI Api response in json format.

I'm using this function to send request

```
export const  getSummary = async (mails:string) =>{
return new Promise(async (resolve,reject)=> {

       const response= await  translator.translate(mails);
       if (!response.success) {
           console.log(response); <--- error happens here
           return reject(response);
    }
    const summarizedMail = response.data;
    console.log(JSON.stringify(summarizedMail,undefined, 2));
    if (summarizedMail.summaryObject.type==="unknown") {
        console.log("I didn't understand the following:");
            console.log(summarizedMail.summaryObject.text);
        
    }
    resolve(response)
})
```

I'm using this schema definition

```
export interface SummarizedMailItems {
    type:'mailSummary';
    summarizationLanguage: 'arabic' | 'english' | 'french' | 'spanish';
    summaryParagraph:string;
    summaryBulletpoints: [string,string,string];
    
}

export interface UnknownText {
    type:'unknown';
    text: string; // The text that wasn't understood
}

export type SummarizedMail = {
    summaryObject: SummarizedMailItems | UnknownText;
};
```

I'm getting this error message :

> { success: false, message: "JSON validation failed: File '/schema.ts'
> is not a module.\n'Object' only refers to a type, but is being used as
> a value here.\nCannot find name 'exports'.\n{\n "paragraphSummary":
> "Discover trends in your work habits with Microsoft Viva Insights. Get
> insights on your work habits in areas such as focus, well-being,
> network, and collaboration. Protect your privacy with Viva Insights.
> Understand and improve your professional habits by reflecting on your
> work methodology. Click on Viva Insights in the Outlook ribbon to view
> your tasks and more.",\n "bulletPointsSummary": [\n "27 days without
> interruption of quiet hours",\n "0% of significant collaboration
> outside of working hours",\n "100% of available time for individual
> work in a normal week"\n ]\n}", }

I notice that in the response I get a JSON format that corresponds to an old json defined

Comment: Can you try this: ` summaryBulletpoints: string[]; // Use an array of strings instead of a tuple`